# Can Multiple Requests overwrite Flow Variables currently in use?

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I am having trouble understanding whether or not I am using the correct variable in the context of my flows.

I have a flow that is exposed via an HTTP Endpoint, in this flow I store data in regards to the incoming request and then proceed to use that Flow Variable containing the data through the flow/subflows.

**My question is, if I have 2 request come in at the same time, will they basically be overwriting the flow-variable causing issues later in the flow chain?**

I want to avoid request 1 setting the Flow Variable, then processing data and continuing to reference the Flow Variable which has been overwritten with data from request 2.

**Is this how this would work? Are each entry into the flow independent of one another?**

Comment: the question title is misleading .. How are you going to differentiate between request1 and request2? Are they both same request?

Comment: They will be coming in through a single endpoint, the content of the request is irrelevant, assuming they are both valid requests that come it at the same time, would they overwrite the flow-variables that are used in a modular flow design?

Comment: The reason I am asking is if they can be differentiated, you can filter it easily ... not necessary the content should be different, other parameters like headers or other params can also differentiate them

Answer (score 1):

> if I have 2 request come in at the same time, will they basically be
>   overwriting the flow-variable causing issues later in the flow chain

**No**. Variables are stored in the message. For every HTTP-request a new message will be created.

you can easily try it out yourself with the following application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd">
    <flow name="foo">
        <http:listener config-ref="user-httpListenerConfig" path="/{test}" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <set-variable variableName="testVariable" value="#[message.inboundProperties['http.uri.params']['test']]" doc:name="testVariable"/>
        <foreach collection="#[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]]" doc:name="For Each">
            <logger message="#[flowVars.testVariable]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            <scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
                <scripting:script engine="Groovy">
                <![CDATA[Thread.sleep(1000)
return payload]]></scripting:script>
            </scripting:component>
        </foreach>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

this is what this application looks like in AnypointStudio:
[image]

just call `http://localhost:8081/foo` from your browser in one tab and `http://localhost:8081/bar` in another tab. you will see both `foo` and `bar` printed alternating in your logs.

Answer (score 0):

Flow variables are instance variables and its created every time for a new request.So, multiple request cannot override the flow variables as every request has their own instance variables.

Answer (score 0):

**"My question is, if I have 2 request come in at the same time, will they basically be overwriting the flow-variable causing issues later in the flow chain?"**
Yes that each correct, with each new request new flow instance, will be created and the variable will be initialized with every new request.
Each request are independent to each other until and unless you use some kind of storage like Object Store to retain the flow variable value from where the request left.
Using memory store like Object store you can retain variable values with each new request otherwise each new request will create new variable instance in the flow